# How do I fill hidden input text fields from url parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running some campaign and would like to get url parameters details submitted with leads/enquiry form to track performance of my campaigns. I am looking for any solution other than php please.

`www.example.com?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=CPC&utm_term=Keywords&utm_content=Content&utm_campaign=Promo%20Code`

My form will have hidden text fields which should be filled with url parameters above. I.e `utm_source`

Comment: mind showing us a snipped of how you have tried to accomplish this?

Comment: To be very honest, I am good with jquery and i do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill a hidden field like any other field :

```
$('#my-field').val(newValue);
```

To get a parameter in the query string of the current location, see this question : [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

With the given function, you can just do this :

```
$(function() {
    $('#my-field').val(getParameterByName('utm_source'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understand your question. But if you want to use the URL of ur current location you can use

```
location.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
location.search.substr(1).split('&').forEach(function (entry) {
  var value = entry.split('=');
  document.querySelectorAll('[name=' + value[0] + ']')[0].value = value[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do it is by having the form inside a frame. You can get your form response inside that same frame while the displayed URL at the browser address bar will not change.